# Vectorize access to columns in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I am trying to get all the indexes that meet a condition in a colum. I've already done this in the case of having one column like this:

```
# Get a 10% of samples labeled with a 1
indexPositive = sample(which(datafsign$result == 1), nrow(datafsign) * .1)
```

It is possible to do the same operation vectoriced for any number of columns in one line as well? I imagine that in that case `indexPositive` would be a list or array with the indexes of each column.

#### Data

The data frame  is as follow:

```
          x         y f1 f2 f3 f4
1  76.71655  60.74299  1  1 -1 -1
2 -85.73743 -19.67202  1  1  1 -1
3  75.95698 -27.20154  1  1  1 -1
4 -82.57193  39.30717  1  1  1 -1
5 -45.32161  39.44898  1  1 -1 -1
6 -46.76636 -35.30635  1  1  1 -1
```

The seed I am using is `set.seed(1000000007)`

What I want is the set of indexes with value 1. In the case of only one column the result is:

```
head(indexPositive)
[1] 1398  873 3777 2140  133 3515
```

Thanks in advance.

### Answer

Thanks to @David Arenburg I finally did it. Based on his comment I created this function:

```
getPercentageOfData <- function(x, condition = 1, percentage = .1){
  # Get the percentage of samples that meet condition
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: A vector containing the data
  #   condition: Condition that the data need to satisfy
  #   percentaje: What percentage of samples to get
  #
  # Returns:
  #   Indexes of the percentage of the samples that meet the condition
  meetCondition = which(x == condition)
  sample(meetCondition, length(meetCondition) * percentage)
}
```

And then I used like this:

```
# Get a 10% of samples labeled with a 1 in all 4 functions
indexPositive = lapply(datafunctions[3:6], getPercentageOfData)
# Change 1 by -1
datafunctions$f1[indexPositive$f1] = -1
datafunctions$f2[indexPositive$f2] = -1
datafunctions$f3[indexPositive$f3] = -1
datafunctions$f4[indexPositive$f4] = -1
```

It would be great to also assign the values -1 to each column at once instead of writing 4 lines, but I do not know how.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example and desired output? If you going to use `sample`, please add a `set.seed`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Updated

Comment: Do you want to sample from rows with _all_ indexes equal to one, or with _any_ index equal to one?

Comment: In the data shown, from f1 I will get all the indexes, 1...6, from f3 I would get 2, 3, 4, 6. ANd from f4 none.

Comment: Your desired output should be according to the provided data set. In your case it seems that the desired output matches your real data. Either way, you can just wrap this into a function such as `f <- function(x) sample(which(x == 1), length(x) * .1)` and then just do `lapply(datafsign, f)` if I understand your question correctly. Of course you can select columns using `lapply(datafsign[3:6], f)` or use `sapply` instead. You could also predefine `nrow(datafsign)` outside the function in order to avoid recalculating it each time.

Comment: I will try it as soon as a can. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Hi, thank you for your comment, it works. If you want, make your comment an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your function as follows (you can also add `replacement` as a partameter)

```
getPercentageOfData <- function(x, condition = 1, percentage = .1, replacement = -1){
  meetCondition <- which(x == condition)
  replace(x, sample(meetCondition, length(meetCondition) * percentage), replacement)
}
```

Then select the columns you want to operate on and update `datafunctions` directly (without creating `indexPositive` and then manually updating)

```
cols <- 3:6
datafunctions[cols] <- lapply(datafunctions[cols], getPercentageOfData)
```

---

You can of course play around with the functions parameters within `lapply` as in (for example)

```
datafunctions[cols] <- lapply(datafunctions[cols], 
                              getPercentageOfData, percentage = .8, replacement = -100)
```